# Fibromyalgia and Neuroplasticity

Tags: pain, nervous-system, fibromyalgia

I am learning that the theory at the moment for Fibromyalgia is that the brain loses it's calibration about how much stimulus is painful or causes pain or like the volume knob is turned up way too high. Has there been studies or research about whether using neuroplasticity could be used to retrain the brain to relearn how painful or not painful a stimulus should be? Can a person with Fibromyalgia unlearn pain?

Comment: See cognitive based therapy for fibromyalgia

Answer (score 1):

In general, for various kinds of pain, you can re-train your brain to block some of the pain signals coming from your body in various ways: TENS, biofeedback, meditation, massage, guided imagery are some methods.[1](http://www.webmd.com/pain-management/guide/11-tips-for-living-with-chronic-pain) Most use mental and physical distraction. Listening to music is an example of mental distraction; TENS is a physical distraction. Some you can learn or use on your own. Others, eg, meditation, TENS, will need an instructor until you can do it on your own.[2](https://theacpa.org/Ten-Steps) Coping with pain is a vast and dynamic field of study these days.